# Stuck mysql left join

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I would like to ask some question as the following:

There are 3 tables, i would like to match value tbl1 on field type-id with id in table

type. i would like to get result as the result that list all type name for each group id.

```
TB1 
Gid TypeID  Value
1   1   5
1   2   10
2   3   6

TBLTYPE
ID  NAME
1   A
2   B
3   C
4   D
5   E


RESULT that i need  

Type  value
A    5
B   10
C   
D   
E   
A   
B   
C   6
D   
E
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this query

```
select  
    tmp.name, 
    tmp.gid, 
    a.value 
from 
    (select 
        a.*, 
        b.* 
    from 
        (select 
            distinct gid 
        from 
            tbl1 a
        )a, 
        tbl2 b
    ) tmp 
left join 
    tbl1 a 
on 
    a.typeid=tmp.id and 
    a.gid = tmp.gid 
order by      --OPTIONAL PART
    tmp.gid
```

### EDIT

The derived table `tmp` is the main table for this query and is derived by a cross join with unique `gid` and tbl2 date which gives each user associated with each group. `tmp` table is left join with tbl1 which the score table which gives the required table.
You can run each derived table separately in fiddle to understand the working properly.

### **[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2cfbc/13)** (each query separately mentioned for proper understanding )

### **[FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2cfbc/12)**

```
| NAME | GID |  VALUE |
-----------------------
|    A |   1 |      5 |
|    B |   1 |     10 |
|    C |   1 | (null) |
|    D |   1 | (null) |
|    E |   1 | (null) |
|    A |   2 | (null) |
|    B |   2 | (null) |
|    C |   2 |      6 |
|    D |   2 | (null) |
|    E |   2 | (null) |
```

Comment: Excellent Meherzad!! but Please explain, I am interested to learn your solution..

Comment: cannot use with temporary table in mysql.

Comment: You cannot refer to a TEMPORARY table more than once in the same query...   http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/temporary-table-problems.html

Comment: Both the table are temp ??

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
TBLTYPE.Name As TYpe
TB1.Value,  
Value,
FROM TB1 
JOIN TBLTYPE on TBLTYPE.Id=TB1.ID
GROUP BY TBLTYPE.Type
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT TBLRESULT.NAME as Type, TB1.Value as value FROM TBLRESULT, TB1 LEFT OUTER JOIN TBLTYPE ON TB1.value = TBLTYPE.ID;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this (basically you need a query for each group):

```
SELECT
    t1.NAME as 'Type',
    IFNULL(t2.Value,'') as 'value'
FROM
    TBLTYPE t1
LEFT JOIN t2
    ON t2.TypeID = t1.ID
    AND t2.Gid = 1
UNION ALL
SELECT
    t1.NAME as 'Type',
    IFNULL(t2.Value,'') as 'value'
FROM
    TBLTYPE t1
LEFT JOIN t2
    ON t2.TypeID = t1.ID
    AND t2.Gid = 2
```

Comment: but group id is null value. how can i set visible value for each group id when union.